# Will there be a Python API for ArcGIS Server?

Tags: python, arcpy, arcgis-server

It seems like an obvious next step given the big push towards Python in ArcGIS Desktop at 10.0.  Are there any limitations of Python compared to javascript, flex, etc that would prevent ESRI from developing a Python API?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Python won't run client-side in the browser, so any server APIs exposed in Python would likely be more in the automation/scripting/admin side of things.

Comment: Well, there is an effort to get Python running client-side here: http://www.skulpt.org/ ...but it isn't anything close to production ready.

Comment: I'd like to see what PyPy does in this area.

Answer (score 3):

There's no browser support for a python interpreter.

I believe you can already use python on the server side (via [geoprocessing](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisserver/10.0/help/arcgis_server_dotnet_help/index.html#/An_overview_of_geoprocessing_with_ArcGIS_Server/009300000028000000/))

Answer (score 3):

You could use python as a client to ArcGIS server. You would just be hitting REST endpoints or maybe *shudder* SOAP endpoints. For instance, I've used python to scrape features from an ArcGIS service via a REST endpoint.

Answer (score 2):

You can use Python Api in ArcGIS server, automating various tasks, like reconcile/post of vresions, registering versioned layers, etc.

**but you'll need a license to use it and ArcMap**. At least in 9.3.1.

Answer (score 0):

You can get IronPython (http://ironpython.net/) running in the client via Gestalt (http://ironpython.net/browser/) and (http://visitmix.com/labs/gestalt/), and at ArcGIS 93 use IronClad (http://code.google.com/p/ironclad/) to access the ArcGIS .pyd, but then this is IronPython rather than CPython, so it really comes back to Esri supporting IronPython or Esri supporting the IronClad project.

Comment: Were you successfull getting IronClad to work with ArcPy?

Comment: I haven't tried since final, but was having issues during the beta program, mostly with loops.